# What are the odds of spinning matching items in a slot machine?

Tags: probability

Lets say we have a slot machine with $5$ reels. Each reel has $5$ different items on it.

What are the odds of spinning $2, 3, 4$ and $5$ matching items?

As I understand the probability of rolling a particular item in each reel is $\frac15$. I just don't know how to calculate the combined probability of these events. Is it simply $\frac15\cdot\frac15$ for two matching items or are things more complicated?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: @5xum OK, sorry, I misunderstood the essence of the site. I thought it's about getting quick answers to clearly formed questions. I'm used to Stack Overflow, so I just thought everything works the same here. I will update my question in a minute.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you also need to post some of your own code if you want a decent answer...

Comment: It helps if you post the code, but still it's all about "do this and it will work" type of answers.

Comment: I updated my question with my own thoughts on the subject. Hope that's enough.

Comment: Thank you. I added an almost complete answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated.

Let's first answer the question what is the probability that there are $5$ matching items

- The number of all possible spins is $5^5$.
- The number of good spins is $5$.
- Therefore, the probability of a good spin is $\frac{5}{5^5}=5^{-4} = 0.16\%$

---

Now, what about four matching items?

The set of all possible spins is now bigger. Let's say that each reel can spin $1,2,3,4$ or $5$. Now, how can we get $4$ same items?

Well, we can have four ones in the first four reels, and one non-one in the fifth reel. There are $4$ such results ($11112,11113,11114,11115$). Then, there are four results for four twos, and four for four threes and so on. So, there are $5\cdot 4=20$ possibilities for having $4$ equal items in the first four reels.

You then also have $20$ possibilities for $4$ equal items on reels $1,2,3,5$, and so on, with a total of $5\cdot 20=100$ good possibilities.

Therefore, the probability of a good spin is $\frac{100}{5^5} = 3.2\%$

---

OK, three matching items. Well:

- there are ${5\choose 2}=10$ possible triplets of reels on which you
- For each such triplet, you have $5$ possibilities for which item will appear on all three. You can then freely choose the other $2$ reels to be anything but the chosen item. Therefore, for each triplet, you have $5\cdot 4\cdot 4$ good spins.

So, $10$ possible triplets and $80$ good rolls for each triplet yields $800$ good spins. With $5^5$ total spins, the probability is
$$\frac{800}{5^5} = 25.6\%$$

---

What about the probability of two matching items? Well, that depends:

- Do you want the probability that there is only one matching pair?
- Do you allow for two pairs?
- Do you allow one pair and one triple?

Comment: Why. The. Hell. Did this answer deserve a downvote?!

Comment: Not everyone is so forthcoming with their vote justifications. (It wasn't me)

Comment: Thanks a lot @5xum that's exactly what I needed. Sorry I can't upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation. About two matching items: let's allow two pairs but no triplet.

Comment: @GiedriusT Then you can follow the same logic as for the triplets, with one more step. You have ${5\choose 2}$ ways of choosing where your pair will appear, and $5$ possibilities for what it is a pair of. The other three reels can contain anything, so $4^3$ options. However, of the $4^3$ options, you need to remove the $5$ options where a triple appears. And then, you have to divide the whole number you get by $2$, because you counted each pair of pairs twice.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but could you please calculate the percentage for me. I know it seems super easy to you, but frankly I don't even know what that (5/2) means nor I understand why it's the same as with three matching items and so on... I understand that this site is all about learning, but I really don't have time for that now and just need a quick answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ${5\choose 2}$ means "the number of subsets of size $2$ in a set of size $5$" in other words "the number of ways I can pick two things out of $5$ if i don't care which one I grab first." Also,  made a mistake in my previous comment. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @GiedriusT The probability of having at least one (and possibly two) pairs and no triple is $\frac{2100}{5^5}=67.2\%$

Comment: Thanks a million! But now i'm interested why are you using (5/2) when counting three matching items. Shouldn't there be (5/3)?

Comment: @GiedriusT Because ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need to multiply $1/25$ with $\binom 5r, r=\{2,3,4,5\}$ as you need to consider permutations of an arrangements on 5 distinct reels and hence consider choosing any two reels to be possible in multiple ways, i.e. $\binom 5r$